# CreateFile / WriteFile is not destroying contents of old file

Tags: c++, visual-c++

The old contents are not being wiped out.
Instead the data is being written over, so I still see old contents.
What did I not do?

```
hFile = CreateFile(fname, // open testfile.txt
    GENERIC_WRITE, // open for reading
    0, // do not share
    NULL, // default security
    OPEN_ALWAYS, // 
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, // normal file
    NULL); // no attribute template

dwBytesToWrite = buff.GetLength();
WriteFile(hFile, buff.GetBuffer(100), dwBytesToWrite, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have specified the wrong value for [`dwCreationDisposition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You need to specify `CREATE_ALWAYS`.

> Creates a new file, always.
>   If the specified file exists and is writable, the function overwrites the file, the function succeeds, and last-error code is set to ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS (183).
>   If the specified file does not exist and is a valid path, a new file is created, the function succeeds, and the last-error code is set to zero.

Answer (score 1):

In dwCreationDisposition you need to specify CREATE_ALWAYS.